# Avoiding writing of same block of statements at different places in one code in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

There are 3 views and one of them is Time view. All 3 views take the same code used for inserting Time factor( financial period, financial year, quarter) for which I have to write same code in all three views.
Please suggest how to do it without writing the whole code each time.

Comment: Create the forth view and put your code there (if the so called code is a sql statement). If the code is a calculation of these values then write UDFs

Comment: would you please explain how to create forth view or give some link to some websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an inline table defined function which accepts a parameter and returns a variety of date functions applied to the parameter. Then use CROSS APPLY to fetch the ones of interest in any given query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor also to achieve the desired result. For example, pass the parameter to the cursor, do the calculation inside of the cursor, then return it.

Cross apply will also work.